# Unlock apex admin account

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I run @apxchpwd.sql 
and unluck the account with this script

```
alter session set current_schema = APEX_050100;
declare
  l_workspace_id number := apex_util.find_security_group_id (p_workspace => 'INTERNAL');
begin
wwv_flow_security.g_security_group_id := 10;

   apex_util.set_security_group_id (p_security_group_id => l_workspace_id);
wwv_flow_fnd_user_api.UNLOCK_ACCOUNT('ADMIN');
commit;
end;
```

But it doest work.
Thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `apxchpwd.sql` script is used to change the password, but it also *unlocks* the ADMIN account (, so - you shouldn't even need any additional code. Just make sure to run the one that belongs to Apex version you use.

```
SQLPLUS /NOLOG
SQL> CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA
SQL> @APXCHPWD
```

Alternatively, also connected as SYS, use the following code:

```
BEGIN
   apex_util.set_security_group_id(p_security_group_id => 10);
   apex_util.unlock_account(p_user_name => 'ADMIN');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't know either. Please, copy/paste your SQL*Plus session which shows what you did and how Oracle responded. Do that by editing your initial message, not as a comment.

Comment: Solved Thanks a lot @Littlefoot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Just being curious: what was it that prevented you from doing it previously?

Comment: I had an issue with using `apxchpwd.sql` and turned out I was trying to invoke an `APEX05000` version of that script in an `APEX050100` instance.

Comment: That's why I said that you should *make sure to run the one that belongs to Apex version you use*, @Mark.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I additionally update expiration date to avoid the issue in the future `UPDATE APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_FND_USER 
SET ACCOUNT_EXPIRY=('01-JAN-2037 00:00:00') where USER_NAME='ADMIN';`

Comment: I'm glad if it helped, @Osama.

Comment: I also added another answer for those didn't work for them :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that worked for me if the above didn't work for you :
credit to : https://ora01948.wordpress.com/2017/12/19/unlock-apex-admin-account/

run the below script **noting that Oracle** `APEX` **schema name can be different in my case it's**
`Apex_050000` **so check your schema name first and change it accordingly** .

```
   `UPDATE Apex_050000.Wwv_Flow_Fnd_User
    SET Web_Password = 'set_new_password'
    WHERE User_Name = 'ADMIN'
    AND Security_Group_Id = 10;
    COMMIT;`
```

now change the session

`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = Apex_050000;`

and run the below script to unlock the account .
     
     `BEGIN
     Wwv_Flow_Security.G_Security_Group_Id := 10;
     Wwv_Flow_Fnd_User_Api.Unlock_Account ('ADMIN');
     COMMIT;
     END;`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step to Unlock Users After execute @apxchpwd.sql in oracle apex 
 - log in as Administration
 - Manage WorkSpaces
 - Manage Developers and Users
 - choose users that you have to unlock
 - account avilability ---> Unlock